# SmartEyeglass: How to view the video that is streamed from the glasses camera

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

The SampleCameraExtension sdk sample allows writing jpegs (7.5 or 15 fps) to a folder on my phone/tablet.  I don't want to store these files, I want to view them (real time) on my tablet (for test) and then (next step) view them (again in real time) from a web browser anywhere. A reply from Sony on another question states to use the "JPEGStream API of the smarteyeglass". I can locate no such api.
Also, the size field in the sony-smarteyeglass-sdk-v1.3.xml (6273014) does not match the size of the zip download (6199654) and will not install in Android Studio (current version) on Windows7. Can this be corrected?

Comment: Hi, it is possible to develop such an application to view images on the phone directly. In fact, we will soon release a demo application for this. I will share it with you as answer as soon as it is published.

Comment: Any chance this demo will also allow streaming to USTREAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SampleCameraExtension uses JPEGStream API and saves stream of images to the folder on the mobile.

You can use this image stream to develop your own application such as live streaming in a webpage or to a live video services.

Sony's developer blog now has an open source application for live streaming. This application uses NodeJS as a server on computer to listen for image stream coming from SmartEyeglass via JPEGStream API.

You can find this application here:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/2016/01/28/livestreaming-app-for-smarteyeglass-available-as-open-source-project/

Size problem with SDK installation XML is fixed. You will be able to install SDK without any issues now.

Comment: Installation of SDK still fails: Downloading Sony SmartEyeglass SDK, Android API 19, revision 6
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 6273014 bytes, got 6199654 bytes.

Comment: @sdrake Please try again after clearing cache of Android SDK Manager from Tools -> Options.